# What are the possible ways to prevent form from double posting in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

During a log inspection of my ASP.NET MVC application I discovered that some users managed to post same form twice. I tried to reproduce it but I failed. Anyway I'd like to prevent users from posting same data twice. Is there any canonical solution for that in ASP.NET MVC or I have to develop my own custom solution?

I case of custom solution I can imagine client side and server side solution. Can you recommend me anything in either case?

Comment: Have you tried hitting F5 to resend post data? This would be the case when you don't use Post-Redirect-Get pattern.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: good tip. Unfortunately the site at which it happens use post-redirect-get pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of three ways to handle this.

1. Have a double post be non-destructive.  That is, when possible make it so that a repost simply refreshes the data in a way that renders it still valid.  This isn't really possible with a post that creates something -- say a credit card transaction -- but should suffice for an update method when you are basically setting new properties.
2. Prevent double posts using a one-time nonce that is only good for one action.  Include a hidden nonce on the page that you track and mark as used once the first post has been seen.  Check this nonce when you get it to make sure that it hasn't been used before and, if it has, show an error message rather than taking an action.
3. Prevent destructive actions by checking uniqueness constraints on the posted data.  This is really a variant on (2) in that your nonce is basically some unique value in the actual data.  This works for some creation scenarios, i.e., you can't create a duplicate user with the same email address, but fails when their is no unique field in the data.  An example of the latter might be a purchase transaction where the user might buy the same item more than one time.

Comment: #2 is a great suggestion (+1 from me). I'd save this value with newly created record.

Comment: @Robert: overriding the first post ins't always option but surely is something that should be considered

Comment: @Jakub: Your comment was probably intended at @tvanfosson not me... ;)

Comment: @Robert: No. You was suggested that at #2 you would save the values from the second post. I think that in many cases it's what user expected to happen however in some cases this isn't option.

Comment: I like solution #2 ... and when the session expires that contains the token, display an error message to refresh their session. I think that's a good compromise.

Answer (score 8):

The usual approach is to disable the submit button immediately after clicking it.

Something like this with jQuery should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myform").submit(function()
        { $("#submit-button").attr("disabled", "disabled"); });
</script>
```

---

Now after reading closely your question and seeing that you use ASP.NET MVC....

The double post is probably caused because users refresh the page after posting it. If you simply return a view from your post action:

```
[AcceptVerbs (HttpVerbs.Pos)]
ActionResult ProcessUserPost ()
{
    /*...*/

    return View ();
}
```

Then the browser will attempt to recreate the page by performing the same steps, meaning submitting the remembered form again. Some browsers will display a warning message (FireFox), the others will just do it quietly (looking at Opera). In order to avoid this you need to assure the page the user is getting is the result of a GET request not POST.

Basically, you need to perform a redirect instead of returning a view. This will instruct the browser to fetch a page again.

```
[AcceptVerbs (HttpVerbs.Pos)]
ActionResult ProcessUserPost ()
{
    /*...*/

    return RedirectToAction ("DisplayTheForm");
}
```

This way refreshing the page won't cause a new POST request being sent.

Of course, this will not prevent your users clicking the back button to return to the form page to submit it again. But that situation should be handled in your business logic, check for double submission of the same order by the same user of whatever it is that you are doing.

Comment: I'll like this solution however this doesn't apply in some weird back button scenarios. (BTW: in my particular case I cannot reproduce double posting even with back button)

Comment: Have you compared META header tags related to caching on your production and your test site? They may differ. And they may be set to refresh data on Back button.

Comment: @Robert: I tested this at production environment. I am suspicious that only IE6 and IE7 are capable of doing this. Anyway how it's happen is only important to avoid it in future.

Answer (score 3):

One technique I have used to prevent a double post is using a server side and client side key that changes with each post. It works like this:

1. Generate a unique (random) key on
   the server and place it in the
   session and also in a hidden field.
2. When the user posts back the first
   time compare the key in the hidden
   field to the key in the session,
   and, if they match, accept the input
   and then change or remove the key
   from the session and update the
   hidden field as well.
3. If the user
   manages to click submit twice the
   second post will fail because the
   hidden field in the HTML will no
   longer match the session variable
   until the page has been refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

### Two step process

**Disable buttons first.**
This will prevent users from submitting the form twice while browser waits for server response. But you should be careful with this one. When user hits submit, you will have to first validate your form (if you use client validation) and when it's valid, imediatelly disable buttons using this code.

```
$(":submit, :button").attr("disabled", true);
```

**Use one of the following redirect action results in your controller**
This will prevent users from hitting F5 after the form has been processes to resend POST data. This is called *POST-REDIRECT-GET* pattern.

```
RedirectToAction();
RedirectToRoute();
Redirect(); // redirects to URL
```

---

**EDIT**
As you've said in comments, your page already uses P-R-G pattern. In this case I'd make sure to implement first step.

Comment: BTW althought I am using Post-Redirect-Get pattern in many cases I always feel bad about additional request which hurts performance.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid excessive requests caused by F5 or reloads or whatever other reason users are doing.